# Discord.js - How do I change bot presence every 15 seconds?

Tags: setinterval, discord.js

I want my bot to change its presence/activity at an interval(15 seconds) but I'm  not sure why one of them isn't working.

```
const botconfig = require("../botconfig.json")

module.exports = async client => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  //client.user.setPresence({game: {name: `(${botconfig.prefix}) for Brain Central`}, type: "WATCHING"})
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    client.user.setPresence({game: {name: `(${botconfig.prefix}) for Brain Central`}, type: "WATCHING"})
    client.user.setPresence({game: {name: `DM to contact staff!`}, type: "PLAYING"})
  }, 15 * 1000)

}
```

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive, are there any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it this way:

```js
// List of available statuses
let statuses = [
    {game: {name: `(${botconfig.prefix}) for Brain Central`}, type: "WATCHING"},
    {game: {name: `DM to contact staff!`}, type: "PLAYING"}
];
// Our pointer
let i = 0;
// Every 15 seconds, update the status
setInterval(() => {
     // Get the status
     let status = statuses[i];
     // If it's undefined, it means we reached the end of the array
     if(!status){
         // Restart at the first status
         status = statuses[0];
         i = 0;
     }
     client.user.setPresence(status);
     i++;
}, 15000);
```